# Mac OS Monterey job script in cron something commands not working

Tags: scripting, cron, macos

I created script backup in `/usr/local/bin/bkpthunderbird.sh`
If i run in terminal `sh bkpthunderbird.sh` is ok!
But, if i put to run in crontab

```
05 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/bkpthunderbird.sh
```

The job runs, but basic commands to check live device for example "ping" or "umount /Volume/destination" or "diskutil unmount /Volumes/destionation" not recognizes.
I gave in Access Full Disk to cron, smbd
In Mac OS Big Sur, Catalina, ... my script in crontab working correctly

Someone know how which why occur this?

Comment: check our PATH. cron has a very limited env. you can define a PATH at the top of your crontab. keep in mind that variable expansion does not happen in the crontab PATH var, so you must expand "$HOME/bin" into "/home/whoever/bin"